# Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE error. Can't access?

Tags: java, android

```
public boolean isOnline() {
    ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) 
             getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    return cm.getActiveNetworkInfo().isConnectedOrConnecting();
}
```

This is the function I want to work.
but I get the error "CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE cannot be resolved or is not a field"
I've added:

```
uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"
uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"
```

to my manifest file.

these are my imports:

```
package com.MTSUAndroid;
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;
import java.sql.*;
import java.util.Calendar;
import javax.naming.Context;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.net.*;
import android.os.*;
import android.widget.*;
import android.text.Html;
import android.text.format.DateFormat;
import android.view.View;

import org.apache.http.util.ByteArrayBuffer;
```

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong if anyone could help..

Answer (score 4):

Instead of importing:

```
import javax.naming.Context;
```

import

```
import android.content.Context;
```

Answer (score 2):

I know this has already been answered (though not accepted for some reason), but I wanted to also put an alternative answer as this one did not answer my questions and I could not find the answer anywhere.

It seems that `CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE` is part of `Activity`, which if your class does not extend `Activity` it throws this error.  To get around that, I just used `getActivity().getSystemService(getActivity().CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE)`.  Hope this helps as well.